# How can I pass python fixture into my class to initialize webdriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox, ui-automation

The purpose is to run tests via pytest in chrome or firefox based on input from the command line. The problem is I am receiving a     `HomePage.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'`      error
Any guess why this is happening and how should I correct my code?
The conftest file is

```
@pytest.fixture
def platform(request):
plat = request.config.getoption('platform').lower()
if plat not in ['chrome', 'firefox']:
raise ValueError('value must be chrome or firefox')
return plat

@pytest.fixture
def driver(platform):
driver = webdriver.Chrome() if platform == 'chrome' else webdriver.Firefox()
yield driver
driver.quit()

@pytest.fixture
def home(driver):
return HomePage(driver)
```

The class in another file is

```
class HomePage(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.driver.maximize_window()
```

The test is

```
 def test_go_to_page(home):
```